# Removing quotes between two strings

Tags: sed

I have a file I am processing and have gotten stuck format is as follows:
    "HostRecord","SOMEFILE","InsideView","legacy.name.com","1.2.3.4","1.2.3.5","some comment",""

I need to remove the "" between the IP addresses, but leave the `,` so in the end I would have the output look like this:
    "HostRecord","SOMEFILE","InsideView","legacy.name.com","1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5","some comment",""

I thought well I just use sed and have tried multiple things. My latest is something like this:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\{1,3\}=1&\)\"\(,=2&\)\"\([0-9]\{1,3\}=3&\)/\1\2\3/'
```

That doesn't seem to have any effect at all, not really picky on a particular tool to do the job, I just need to get it completed. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: If the IP is always in the same relative position, why not just access those elements specifically and manually remove the "? e.g. `list[4] = list[4][:-1]; list[5] = list[5][1:]`.

Comment: So some clarity I suppose might help, the file is about 200k lines long, and not all entries have multiple IP's and some lines have dozens of IP's.  What I wanted to do was just to make a quick pattern match between the last octet the "," and the first octet of the next IP and just strip the " out

Comment: So how do you know when the IP's stop?

Comment: unfortunately I don't, I do know they always start at field 5

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something that has real CSV processing? Assuming you gather IP addresses until you get to something that doesn't *look* like an IP address, this should work:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  cout = CSV.new $stdout, force_quotes: true
  CSV.new(ARGF).each do |row|
    out_row = row.shift(4)
    ips = row.shift
    while row[0] =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/ 
      ips += ",#{row.shift}"
    end
    cout << out_row + [ ips ] + row
  end' infile.csv >outfile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a flag available in the substitution "s" command ,(like the common g,p, or d flag) we can only substitute a Nth occurence. So, for example:

```
<file sed  's/"//10'
```

will remove the 10th double quote ' " '.

```
<file sed -e 's/"//11' -e 's/"//10'
```

will remove the 11th quote and then the 10th quote on every line.

```
sed 's|\([0-9]\)","\([0-9]\)|\1,\2|g'
```

This will save each single digit `[0-9]` found surrounding a `","` into two groups. We can then replace the pattern with the first group `\1`, followed by a comma `,`, followed by the second group `\2`. We add the "g" flag which makes the substitute command work on every occurrence found on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a file `test_sed` with the following lines:

```
"HostRecord","SOMEFILE","InsideView","legacy.name.com","1.2.3.4","1.2.3.5","some comment",""
"HostRecord","SOMEFILE","InsideView","legacy.name.com","1.2.3.4","1.2.3.5","10.10.10.10","192.168.1.12","some comment",""
```

Use two `sed` commands though *pipeline* sequence(output redirection):

```
cat test_sed | sed -re 's#"(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})","(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})"#"\1,\3"#gp;' 
    | sed -rn 's#,(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})","(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}),#,\1,\3,#gp;'
```

The output:

```
"HostRecord","SOMEFILE","InsideView","legacy.name.com","1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5,10.10.10.10,192.168.1.12","some comment",""
"HostRecord","SOMEFILE","InsideView","legacy.name.com","1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5,10.10.10.10,192.168.1.12","some comment",""
```

`([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})` represents IP address